# Кто такая невестка?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Если мне не изменяет память, происхождение названия родни тут когда-то уже обсуждалось, но я повторяю вопрос, потому что вчера услышал любопытную вещь: мол, слово "невестка" происходит от "невесть кто" - то есть сын привел в семью неизвестную девушку, "невесть кого".  
Правда ли это? И если да, еще один вопрос: а каково происхождение слова "невеста"? Родственно ли оно "невестке"?  
К слову, в чешском "невестка" - это ругательство, сродни русскому слову на вторую букву.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этом слове известный современный этимолог М.Фасмер пишет: "Тут самым лучшим толкованием еще остается самое старое, объясняющее его как "неизвестная". И впрямь у него тот же корень, что и предыдущего (Невежда, невежа  -  ***прим. мое.***). "Невеста" - новый член семьи, пока еще "неведомый" своим будущим родственником, "незнакомка". Ведь в старинных русских песнях и жених (с точки зрения невесты) тоже нередко называется "чижен*И*ном", "чужим".  (Почему не иначе? Этимологический словарь школьника. Лев Успенский).

Answer (score 3):

Черных считает слова "невеста и невестка" однокоренными, учитывая, что   в некоторых случаях жену сына также называли  невестой.

Слово "невеста" образовано сложением корней двух слов: новый и вести, то есть невеста - это нововведенная.

Однако в дальнейшем, возможно, сказалось влияние глагола "ведать" - знать. С одной стороны, это невинность/неведение невесты, а с другой - ее статус нового, "неведомого" человека в семье.

Comment: >Слово "невеста" образовано сложением корней двух слов: новый и вести, то есть невеста - это нововведенная.

Насчёт "новый" - простите, боюсь немного сомнительная версия. Слово **"невеста"** начинается с **"нев"**. Для славянских языков это не характерно, чтобы **"нев"** означало **"новый".** Это же не английский. 

В славянских языках используется корень **"нов-"**. В старославянском в том числе.

Comment: У Черных: о.-с. слово nev-ved-t-a, nev/neu, восходит к и.-е. neu(os) - новый.

Answer (score 1):

Слово произошло от невесть - кто. Нужно рассматривать и другие славянские языки. Nevěstka на чешском - проститутка, девка какая-то. Когда сын приводил девушку в семью, она просто девка и должна заслужить уважение. А когда рожала, становилась снохой. От слова сношаться ( иметь отношения).